# jQuery Fullcalendar date/time not showing the time range

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create an event using the jQuery plugin "fullcalendar". I have created an event with the code below but it does not come out correctly, the event displays "7pGrant Andrews & Lily Brooke Live w/ support @ The Black Bull", when it should display the time range then the event name.

How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        events: [{
            title: 'Grant Andrews & Lily Brooke Live w/ support @ The Black Bull',
            start: '2014-05-23 19:00:00',
            end: '2014-05-23 21:00:00',
            allDay: false,
        },

        })
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's like this in the demo.
where you are in Monthview you see just the hour + A or P
in week view you see the range time.

Comment: So how do I correctly display the time of the event?